# How to update app in iOS app store if programming language changes?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I have an application written using native iOS with offline db feature. Now we are planning to rewrite the application using React native and submit it again to app store with same bundle id, and by updating version number.

Problem is i have offline db in old app. And that may contain data created by user. If i develop the same application using react native and push it as an update to app store, will the offline db get affected?

Will all the data stored persist or  it will be installed as a new fresh application with no saved offline data?

What will be the impact for my existing app in app store and what is the app store submission process for this kind of requirement?

Comment: Which offline db do you refer to?

Comment: I used Core data to store offline data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is i have offline db in old app. And that may contain data
>   created by user. If i develop the same application using react native
>   and push it as an update to app store, will the offline db get
>   affected?

It depends what are you doing with the new application. In general it will remain untouched.

> Will all the data stored persists or it will be installed as a new
>   fresh application with no saved offline data?

All the data will persists.

> What will be the impact for my existing app in app store and what is
>   the app store submission process for this kind of requirement?

The submission process is the same as an update to this version. What do you mean by "impact"? The users will see it as an update. If you need to keep a login or maintain the previous data it's the job of the new app to migrate the data or to read them in the database.

To try an update you can install the old app from Xcode and then install the new one without deleting it. Make sure to use the same provisioning profile.

Comment: Will i be able to access the data from same db and do the updates as i did earlier(using native iOS), with react native now? Also if i add a new field to the existing database and still use react native to perform CRUD operations, will it work without any issue?